# Is there a web part the will display Quicktime (.mov) files?

Tags: web-part, web, video

Ideally like the media web Part displays .wmv files, but it could be some pre-existing webpart that simply writes the proper EMBED code to the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the out of the box Content Editor Webpart to include custom html on a page.

Answer (score 0):

Costs $75 USD, but will do the trick - [AE Media Player](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5747)